# jQuery won't work with simple_form in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css

I'm trying to just include some basic jQuery in a Simple_form generated scaffold in Rails to hide certain elements. For reasons I don't understand, jQuery doesn't seem to be working at all. The layout file has the correct javascript include tag. I'm wondering if I'm just making a basic CSS/jQuery error or if there is something going on with Rails I need to fix.

Here is the form:

```
<div class = "check1" >
    <%= f.input :use_current_location?, input_html: {checked: true } %>
  </div>
  <div class = "hidden1">
    <%= f.input :address_line_1 %>
    <%= f.input :address_line_2 %>
    <%= f.input :address_line_3 %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :postcode %>
    <%= f.input :country %>
  </div>
  <div class = "check2">
    <%= f.input :available_now?, input_html: {checked: true } %>
  </div>
  <div class = "hidden2">
    <%= f.input :available_from? %>
    <%= f.input :time %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm just trying to hide certain classes of the form. The jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".hidden1").hide(); //Initially hides selected classes.
    $(".hidden2").hide();
});
```

I am wondering if it is something to do with the js tag. Layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><!-- YOUR APP NAME--></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "appication" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render :partial => ('layouts/navbar') %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. If anyone can also recommend a different form generator that would also be great.

I am running Rails 4/Ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing out the same code in different projects it appears to be a problem with simple_form overriding the javascript files. I have found that the same thing happens using formtastic. I still don't know why this is but the issue can be avoided by not using a form generator and using the default scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

Missing the closing parenthesis on the last line. Try });

Comment: Thanks, good spot. Unfortunately it was actually correct in the document, I just copied it across incorrectly. It's still not working. I think the tags might be wrong or perhaps I have not 'required' the js correctly in application.js. Does this file have to be edited at all from default?